# Why 'django.contrib.admin.sites' has no attribute 'register'?

Tags: python, django

i make the model in app but when i call this function 'admin.sites.register(modal_class_name)' in admin.py file. i got an error

here is my modal class

```
    from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Topic(models.Model):
    top_name=models.CharField(max_length=256,unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.top_name


class Webpage(models.Model):
    topic=models.ForeignKey(Topic,Topic)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=256,unique=True)
    url=models.URLField(unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class AccessRecord(models.Model):
    name=models.ForeignKey(Webpage,Webpage)
    date=models.DateField()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.date)
```

**and Here is my admin.py file code**

```
from django.contrib import admin

# Register your models here.
from first_app.models import AccessRecord, Topic, Webpage

admin.sites.register(AccessRecord)
admin.sites.register(Topic)
admin.sites.register(Webpage)
```

and when i run the project the error appears,which is following
[error snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WdBQo.png)

Comment: admin.site.regitster(AccessRecord), remove 's'

Comment: its worked thanks @bmons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is typo in your code. Its site instead of sites.

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin

# Register your models here.
from first_app.models import AccessRecord, Topic, Webpage

admin.site.register(AccessRecord)
admin.site.register(Topic)
admin.site.register(Webpage)
```